# Laravel Echo.join working only Echo.channel and Echo.private not working

Tags: vuejs2, laravel-5.4, broadcasting, laravel-echo

I am using laravel 5.4 and pusher for event broadcasting. I create a  private channel  "chatroom".

```
Echo.join('chatroom')  /// Work Well 
   .listen('MessagePosted', (e) => {
           this.messages.push({
           body: e.message.body
       });
});
```

But this is not working with Channel and Private...

```
 Echo.channel('chatroom')   OR 
 Echo.private('chatroom')   //// Not Working
```

Getting following error [image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to put this inside `mounted()` method. Because error answered that `.here` is not a function

```
  mounted(){
    Echo.private('chat')
    .listen('ChatEvent', (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });

    //Make function for joining and leaving for any users
    Echo.join('chat')
    .here((users) => {
        console.log(users)
    })
    .joining((user) => {
        console.log(user.name)
    })
    .leaving((user) => {
        console.log(user.name)
    });

  }
```

And if you make private chat , then in `routes/channels.php` , you've to define/register a channel named `chat` like this -

```
Broadcast::channel('chat', function($user){
  return ['name' => $user->name]; //Return data as your need
});
```

Hope, it will help someone.